# Why are 'char' and 'wchar_t' shows different result when they have the same value?

Tags: c, char, wchar-t

```
#include <stdio.h>

wchar_t wc = ' 459';

printf ("%d", wc);         //result : 13625
printf( "%c", wc);         //result : 9

wc = L' 459';

printf ("%d", wc);         //result : 32
printf( "%c", wc);         //result : (space)
```

Why are the results all different?
I know the first result is a converted ASCII code of '59' but the rest 3 results are complete mystery.

Comment: The `sizeof(wchar_t)` is `2` so it can't hold the value you propose. The `sizeof(' 459')` is `4`. Note that `printf("%X", ' 459');` outputs `20343539`.

Comment: KamilCuk// Value between single quotation marks without prefix is 'char type character literal' as far as I know.

Comment: A "character literal" is type `int` not `char`. Try `sizeof('a')`.

Comment: Weather Vane// I still don't get it. Could you please explain more about the rest 3 results?

Comment: user694733// Ok done. It was my fault sorry.

Comment: On a little-endian machine the first byte (restricted by `%c`) of the argument is `'9'`, the first 2-bytes (restricted by `wc`) are `13625` which is `0x3539` the last 2 character values.

Comment: The result is implementation-defined. Citing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal: `'c-char-sequence'` Ordinary multicharacter literal, e.g. 'AB', is conditionally-supported, has type int and implementation-defined value. `L'c-char-sequence'` Wide multicharacter literal, e.g. L'AB', is conditionally-supported, has type wchar_t and implementation-defined value. ...

Comment: ... Multicharacter literals were inherited by C from the B programming language. Although not specified by the C or C++ standard, most compilers (MSVC is a notable exception) implement multicharacter literals as specified in B: the values of each char in the literal initialize successive bytes of the resulting integer, in big-endian zero-padded right-adjusted order, e.g. the value of `'\1'` is `0x00000001` and the value of `'\1\2\3\4'` is `0x01020304`.

Comment: @Bodo MSVC does that too, as shown by my first comment (output from MSVC).

Comment: @Bodo That... is the exact answer I've looking for. Now I understand why the wchar_t type input shows the first character(space) rather than the last character(9). Thanks so much.

Comment: @WeatherVane All text after "*Citing URL*", continued in the next comment, is a citation of the specified source. I don't know what difference in MSVC's implementation it refers to, and I don't know if it is correct at all.

Comment: @Bodo part of the citation, thanks.